# Unity3D shader bug on ios device

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, shader

I use water shader but it bug when build to ios device (still work fine on android, editor, mac).[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhI6z.png)

[Bug on ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WzSD.png)

Bug: Plane has shader alway on top of screen and plane has been upside down.

I already debug on device but nothing error ...

Here is shader code

```
Shader "RealisticWater/WaterMobile" {
Properties {
    _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _ReflectionColor ("Reflection Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _Wave1 ("Wave1 Distortion Texture", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _Wave2 ("Wave2 Distortion Texture", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _Cube("Reflection Map", Cube) = "" {}
    _Direction ("Waves Direction 1 & 2", Vector) = (1.0 ,1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
    _FPOW("FPOW Fresnel", float) = 5.0
    _R0("R0 Fresnel", float) = 0.05
    _OffsetFresnel("Offset Fresnel", float) = 0.1

    _Distortion  ("Distortion", float) = 500
    _DistortionVert  ("Per Vertex Distortion", Float) = 1

    _GAmplitude ("Wave Amplitude", Vector) = (0.1 ,0.3, 0.2, 0.15)
    _GFrequency ("Wave Frequency", Vector) = (0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 1.8)
    _GSteepness ("Wave Steepness", Vector) = (1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0)
    _GSpeed ("Wave Speed", Vector) = (-0.23, -1.25, -3.0, 1.5)
    _GDirectionAB ("Wave Direction", Vector) = (0.3 ,0.5, 0.85, 0.25)
    _GDirectionCD ("Wave Direction", Vector) = (0.1 ,0.9, 0.5, 0.5) 

    _WaveScale("Waves Scale", float) = 1
    _TexturesScale("Textures Scale", Float) = 1
}

Category {

    Tags { "Queue"="Transparent+1" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    ZWrite Off
    Cull Off 

    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent+1" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        Pass {



CGPROGRAM

#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
#pragma glsl_no_auto_normalization
#pragma target 3.0
#pragma multi_compile cubeMap_on cubeMap_off
//#pragma glsl

#include "UnityCG.cginc"
fixed _WaveScale;
float _TexturesScale;
fixed4 _Color;
fixed4 _GlareColor;
fixed4 _ReflectionColor;
sampler2D _GrabTextureMobile;
fixed4 _GrabTextureMobile_TexelSize;
sampler2D _Wave1;
sampler2D _Wave2;
samplerCUBE _Cube;   
fixed4 _Direction;
fixed _FPOW;
fixed _R0;
fixed _OffsetFresnel;
fixed _Distortion;
fixed _DistortionVert;
sampler2D _ReflectionTex;
fixed _Bias;
fixed _Scale;
fixed _Power;
fixed _Shininess;
fixed4 _LightColor0; 

fixed4 _GAmplitude;
fixed4 _GFrequency;
fixed4 _GSteepness;                                     
fixed4 _GSpeed;                 
fixed4 _GDirectionAB;       
fixed4 _GDirectionCD;

fixed4 _Wave1_ST;
fixed4 _Wave2_ST;
fixed4 _Wave3_ST;

sampler2D _WaterDisplacementTexture;


struct appdata_t {
    fixed4 vertex : POSITION;
    fixed2 texcoord: TEXCOORD0;
    fixed3 normal : NORMAL;
};

struct v2f {
    fixed4 vertex : POSITION;
    fixed4 uvgrab : TEXCOORD0;
    fixed4 uvWave12 : TEXCOORD1;
    fixed4 offset : TEXCOORD2;
    #if cubeMap_on
    fixed3 reflectionDir : TEXCOORD3;
    #endif
};


v2f vert (appdata_t v)
{
    v2f o;

    fixed2 time1 = fixed2(fmod(_Time.x*_Direction.x, 1), fmod(_Time.x*_Direction.y, 1));
    fixed2 time2 = fixed2(fmod(_Time.x*_Direction.z, 1), fmod(_Time.x*_Direction.w, 1));

    fixed3 posWorld = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
    fixed2 scaleeUv = -posWorld.xz / _TexturesScale;
    o.uvWave12.xy = scaleeUv * _Wave1_ST.xy + _Wave1_ST.w  + time1;
    o.uvWave12.zw = scaleeUv * _Wave2_ST.xy + _Wave2_ST.w  + time2;


    //--------------------Gerstner waves-------------
    fixed2 vtxForAni = posWorld.xz / _WaveScale;    

    fixed3 offsets;
    fixed4 AB = _GSteepness.xxyy * _GAmplitude.xxyy * _GDirectionAB.xyzw;
    fixed4 CD = _GSteepness.zzww * _GAmplitude.zzww * _GDirectionCD.xyzw;

    fixed4 dotABCD = _GFrequency.xyzw * fixed4(dot(_GDirectionAB.xy, vtxForAni), dot(_GDirectionAB.zw, vtxForAni), dot(_GDirectionCD.xy, vtxForAni), dot(_GDirectionCD.zw,  vtxForAni));
    fixed4 TIME = fmod(_Time.y * _GSpeed, 6.2831);

    fixed4 COS = cos (dotABCD + TIME);
    fixed4 SIN = sin (dotABCD + TIME);

    offsets.x = dot(COS, fixed4(AB.xz, CD.xz));
    offsets.z = dot(COS, fixed4(AB.yw, CD.yw));
    offsets.y = dot(SIN, _GAmplitude);

    //------------------------------------------------

    v.vertex.xyz += offsets;    
    fixed4 oPos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);   

    #if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
    fixed scale = -1.0;
    #else
    fixed scale = 1.0;
    #endif

    o.uvgrab.xy = (fixed2(oPos.x, oPos.y*scale) + oPos.w) * 0.5;
    o.uvgrab.zw = oPos.zw;
    o.uvgrab.xy += (offsets.xz + offsets.y*offsets.y)/_DistortionVert;

    fixed3 normWorld = normalize(mul((fixed3x3)(unity_ObjectToWorld), v.normal).xyz);

    #if cubeMap_on
    fixed3 normalDir = normalize(mul(float4(v.normal, 0.0), unity_WorldToObject).xyz);
    o.reflectionDir = reflect(posWorld - _WorldSpaceCameraPos, normalDir);
    #endif

    o.offset.xy = _Distortion*fixed2(0.001, 0.001);
    o.offset.zw = o.offset.xy/30;
    o.offset.xy = o.offset.xy*o.offset.xy*o.offset.xy;

    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
    return o;
}


fixed4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR
{   
    fixed2 normal1 = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_Wave1, i.uvWave12.xy)).rg;
    fixed2 normal2 = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_Wave2, i.uvWave12.zw + normal1)).rg;

    fixed2 offset = normal2 * normal2 * normal2 * i.offset.xy + normal2 * i.offset.zw;

    i.uvgrab.xy = offset * i.uvgrab.z + i.uvgrab.xy;
    #if UNITY_VERSION >= 460
    fixed4 coord = UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.uvgrab);
    #else
    fixed4 coord = i.uvgrab;
    #endif
    fixed3 reflection;
    #if cubeMap_off
    reflection = tex2Dproj(_ReflectionTex, coord).rgb * _ReflectionColor.rgb;
    #endif
    #if cubeMap_on
    reflection =  texCUBE(_Cube, i.reflectionDir) * _ReflectionColor.rgb;
    #endif
    fixed3 grab = tex2Dproj(_GrabTextureMobile, coord).rgb;

    fixed3 col = grab * _Color.rgb + reflection  + reflection * offset.x * 10;

    return fixed4(col, 1);
}
ENDCG
        }
    }


    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Fallback for older cards and Unity non-Pro

    SubShader {
        Blend DstColor Zero
        Pass {
            Name "BASE"
            SetTexture [_MainTex] { combine texture }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry if my english not good. Thanks you guys !